# Serializer a method just from a specify Controller - Spring, JSON Jackson

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I have 2 controllers and a get method for a field with custom serialization like as `@JsonSerialize(using = MySerialization.class)`.

But I want to make this serialization just when I call method from A Controller, not from B Controller.

How I can specify this?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I will assume that you have the follow requestmaps

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveA", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Person getPersonA() {
    return getPerson();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/saveB", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Person getPersonB() {
    return getPerson();
}

private Person getPerson() {
    return new Person("Elvis");
}

static class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

So you want to serialize the **Person** object in different ways at each requestMap, I personally could not found (even see) a Spring Solution for that, I think that is a Jackson and Java problem to be solved, so here is my solution:

Create a **Person** subclass then customize it as you need, for example

```
static class CustomPerson extends Person {

    public CustomPerson(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @JsonSerialize(using = NameSerializer.class)
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    }
}

static class NameSerializer extends JsonSerializer {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString("customSerializer-" + String.valueOf(value));
    }
}
```

Then, all you need to do is create a mapper method, that converts your **Person** to a **CustomPerson**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveB", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Person getPersonB() {
    return getCustomPerson();
}

private Person getCustomPerson() {
    return new CustomPerson(getPerson().getName());
}
```

Another option is to create the object mapper and serialize the Object as you want when you need it customized:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveC", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getPersonC(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    new ObjectMapper()
    .registerModule(new SimpleModule().addSerializer(Person.class, new JsonSerializer<Person>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Person value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField("name", "Custom-" + value.getName());
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }))
    .writeValue(response.getWriter(), getPerson());
}
```