# Spring boot dynamic/annotation custom JSON deserializer

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

i have written custom JSON deserializer and it's working like expected, but my problem is that it is always ON because it is defined on configuration level.

I want to disable it on some custom annotation on method or controller level, so it doesn't work when that annotation is present, but when there is no annotation the custom JSON deserializer works. Is that possible ?

My code for deserializer :

```
@Configuration
public class OwaspConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(jsonConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverter<?> jsonConverter() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(String.class, new DefaultJsonSerializer());
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build();
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }

}

public class DefaultJsonSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    public static final org.owasp.html.PolicyFactory POLICY_FACTORY = new HtmlPolicyBuilder().toFactory();

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String value = parser.getValueAsString();
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value))
            return value;
        else {
            String originalWithUnescaped = unescapeUntilNoHtmlEntityFound(value);
            return unescapeEntities(POLICY_FACTORY.sanitize(originalWithUnescaped), true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property)
            throws JsonMappingException {
        return this;
    }

    private String unescapeUntilNoHtmlEntityFound(final String value) {
        String unescaped = unescapeEntities(value, true);
        if (!unescaped.equals(value))
            return unescapeUntilNoHtmlEntityFound(unescaped);
        else
            return unescaped;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check this answer that shows how to use a serializer for a specific field: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099529/serializer-a-method-just-from-a-specify-controller-spring-json-jackson

Comment: You might be looking for [JSON Views](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation)?

Answer (score 0):

use [@JsonDeserialize](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) - *Annotation use for configuring deserialization aspects, by attaching to "setter" methods or fields, or to value classes*

in your DTO

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = StringDeserializer.class)
public String heading;
```

Deserializer Class

```
public class StringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return p.getValueAsString();
    }

}
```